# Asymmetric cryptography using hazmat.primitives. - ValueError: Encryption/Decryption failed

Tags: python, encryption, padding

I'm trying to write a basic script to encrypt/decrypt some files on-the-go.
The issue here is apparently relating to the padding method or to the size itself of the RSA key (as far as I understood from the online resources I've checked and currently checking).

More specifically, while debugging my code, I saw that it works if the contents of the files are inferior to a certain number of bytes (I'm testing with a text file, so it's easy to play around with its contents). So if, for example, the file is empty, the encryption goes well, but if I paste a large portion of text, I got a `Value Error: Encryption/Decryption failed`.

This is my function for encrypting:

```
def encrypt_things(key, path):
    with open(path, "rb") as file:
        data = file.read()

    data_encrypted = pubkey.encrypt(data, padding.OAEP(
                                    mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA256()),
                                    algorithm=hashes.SHA256(), label=None))
    encrypted_file = path + ".hi"
    try:
        with open(encrypted_file, "wb") as destination:
            destination.write(data_encrypted)
    except:
        print("Error to encrypt")
```

Comment: You can only encrypt data with RSA whose length is at most equal to the key size. In fact, the maximum data length is even smaller, since the padding also requires space. For a 2048 bits key (256 bytes) and OAEP with SHA256, the data may be a maximum of 190 bytes, see [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/42100). For larger data, use [symmetric encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric-key_algorithm) (e.g. AES/GCM) or [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem).

Comment: In your opinion, should i do that with Fernet and then using hazmat to rsa-encrypt the fernet key?

Comment: Fernet is a symmetric authenticated encryption and is one possible option. Another option is AES-GCM, which is also a symmetric  authenticated encryption. 
I don't want to make a recommendation here, both are described in detail on the web, so you can make up your own mind (taking into account your specific requirements).